# Emacs keybindings don't work with Windowbuilder

Tags: eclipse, windowbuilder

I'm using WindowBuilder (0.9.0.r36x201102111130) together with Emacs keybindings, but inside the WindowBuilder source editor, the Emacs copy/paste commands do not work. I've tried to search for any commands defined by WindowBuilder which might cause the conflict, but without any luck.

Anybody familiar with this problem?